# php mt_rand and google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, ab-testing, multivariate-testing

I've been using `mt_rand(1,6)`, which, depending on the random integer generated, a different CSS style would be used (for MVT).

Is there any reason, in terms of the PHP function, why Analytics would say there is a drastic (>5% in some cases) difference in *Unique* visitors (~5K in total )? I assumed this should be closer to 0.

So, is it more likely that this is the result of some statistic on Google's end and **not** the *fault* of php, or is there a better function I should be using?

Comment: That's very difficult to answer as we can't see just how different the MVT CSS differences might be. If they are drastic, then you can expect far more than >5%. Interestingly, entropy is a tricky subject - true entropy is difficult to achieve without including chaotic elements.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand, even if some pages do attract more traffic, if all pages are 'evenly' distributed, shouldn't i see an even distribution in unique visits, regardless of the sites content/seo?

Comment: Then the `mt_rand()` function isn't your best bet as it will allocate traffic on a less than distributed basis. Better to cycle through (round-robin fashion!) so that each option receives the same number of visitors/traffic. Then you will see which proves the most popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mt_rand()` won't distribute traffic/options evenly. Quite the opposite. It might be that randomly selected options delivers traffic to: `1,1,6,6,6,6,6,6,3`

Your best bet is to use a 'round-robin' method, that equally distributes traffic through your MVT (multi-variate testing) - cycling through: `1,2,3,4,5,6` and repeat.

There are many ways to do it in PHP, but simplistically, Pseudo-code would be:

```
Render v1,
Write increment to file/DB
Render v2,
Write increment to file/DB
etc..
Reaching v6, reset to v1
```

Applying approximately equal load to each (of 6?) should yield more accurate results as each potential option/version will receive the same. More complex MVT isn't needed here.

Interestingly, where I've used it before, we've always allocated traffic on a % basis (rather than random) as we can make qualified decisions based on the results. If you don't serve each option equally, then you can't compare results!!

Hope this helps further.